# SPList.GetItems query returning an invalid SPListItemCollection. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: development, list, spquery

I'm trying to query an SPList object using a CAML query (see code below).

```
SPQuery queryGetExistingTargetTask = new SPQuery();
queryGetExistingTargetTask.Query = string.Format(@"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""TaskID""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">{0}/Value></Eq></Where>", System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(Convert.ToString(sourceTask["TaskID"])));
SPListItemCollection matchedTargetTasks = destinationList.GetItems(queryGetExistingTargetTask);

if (matchedTargetTasks.Count == 1) {...}
```

The `SPList.GetITems` call isn't throwing an error and it does return a SPListItemCollection Object. However, when I try to access any of the properties on the collection they throw an unhelpful error (see image below).

[image]

I'm fairly new to SharePoint development, so there is a good chance I am doing something very wrong here. Can you guys see anything obviously wrong with this code?

What I've tried so far:
 - I confirmed that the destinationList (an SPList) is a valid instance of the correct list.
 - Checked and re-checked the query in CAML builder

Note: This particular query should might (and will in my demo data) return no hits. However, I'd assume it would still return an object with a 0 value in the count property. Or am I mistaken about that?

Comment: Your CAML query is missing an angle bracket before /Value.

Comment: Did that fix it? I'll pop it in as an answer so can be marked correct.

Comment: Added anyway :)

Comment: It did fix it. I feel like a dolt for missing something so obvious, but I appreciate that sometimes fresh perspective is the best debugging tool.

Comment: Totally - CAML usually doesn't have intellisense so I know if there's CAML then the problem is there, the rest of the code is usually fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CAML query is missing an angle bracket before /Value.